# Java desktop notifications Ubuntu

Tags: java, swing, ubuntu, notifications, system-tray

Ubuntu has desktop notifications at the bottom of the screen. My question is how to use it with Java. I couldn't find a solution for this. I use Gnome-shell, but does it work on the same way with Unity? And has Debian also the same notification system? And if you know the answer, I hope you will give an example so I'll understand it better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [SystemTray](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/SystemTray.html) and [TrayIcon](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/TrayIcon.html) should do what you need. If not, maybe [Twinkle](http://blog.swingfx.ch/twinkle-100) will:

> Twinkle lets you create desktop notifications from your Java Swing
>   application with ease!

Answer (score 3):

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use The System Tray](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/systemtray.html) for a working example.